Execute Bibliography Options just for a type
I need to customize the bibliographic style and I need to use the \autocite command to easily switch its output according to the type of bibliographic entry: in my specific case, I want autocite=inline only for @entrytype of my new creation. For the purposes of an MWE, I think it is enough to ask you how to customize autocite just for a conventional type, such as @article, in order to make this option different from the default.
I tried to insert the option inside the square brackets in the \ExecuteBibliographyOptions command. In this way, I wanted to define autocite by default inside the square brackets of the package itself (but I could also do it in the \ExecuteBibliographyOptions command without square brackets) and, in the next line, define an \ExecuteBibliographyOptions valid, indeed, only for my @entrytype (in the MWE it is @article).
However, it doesn't work: the output gives my the following error: «Package keyval Error: autocite undefined». Two times in the main.tex and one time in the output.bbl.
Here is an MWE of mine. I have left between the comments the possibility of creating a new name for \DeclareAutoCitecommand and the possibility of referring \autocite to completely new \DeclareCiteCommands.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
% \DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\parencite}{\parencites}
% \DeclareAutoCiteCommand{customedinline}{\customedcite}{\customedcites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[article]{autocite=inline}

\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
@book{contini2015,
    author={Contini, Francesco},
    title={My First Book},
    publisher={Penguin},address={London},
    year={2015},edition={1}}
@article{contini2016,
    author={Contini, Francesco},
    title={My First Article},
    journal={The Journal to Trying},volume={5},
    publisher={Penguin},address={London},
    year={2016}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{main.bib}

\title{Options MWE}
\author{Francesco Contini}
\date{July 2024}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\autocite{contini2015}
\autocite{contini2016}
\end{document}

Update for @moeve.
The question arises from the need to cite bib sources which have got a protocol number and year and which are unequivocally identifiable through these last two data (let's call it @protocol). For example, laws have a number and year of enactment; one may prefer to leave numerous other information in a final bibliography. At the bottom of my question, I will add the definition of the cite macro that I am giving to this @protocol, with a new toggle. The aim is that the user can use \autocite for any type of entry, but that this \autocite always behaves in the same way with my @protocol, no matter if the default option for any other entrytype is «plain», «inline» same, «footnote» same, «smart» etc.: that is, if the toggle is activated, \autocite (of @protocol) goes in the text (regardless of the definition for other entries) and in the short form; if the toggle is deactivated, \autocite (of @protocol) goes in a footnote and in the long form at the first citation and in the short form at the following ones.
\letbibmacro*{dft}{cite}
\renewbibmacro{cite}{%
    \ifentrytype{protocol}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:protocol}}%
        {\usebibmacro{dft}}}

\newbibmacro{cite:protocol}{%
    \iftoggle{bbx:protocolshort}%
        {\ifciteseen%
            {\usebibmacro{cite:protocol:short}}%
            {\usebibmacro{cite:protocol:toggleciteshort}}}%
        {\ifciteseen%
            {\usebibmacro{cite:protocol:short}%
            \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
            \printtext{\bibstring{cit}}}%
            {\usebibmacro{cite:protocol:full}}}}


autocite options are global settings that can't be changed per type. If you can share slightly more (high-level) details, it might be possible to come up with a solution that works "inside" \autocite definitions by branching in the relevant bibmacros. What probably won't work is something like parenthetical citations for some types, footnotes for others, because that will just look odd if you cite several works of different type at once (you may not want to do that, but usually biblatex commands are coded so that they should cover such a situation as well).

Ok. You can read my comment at the bottom of my question: I am going to update it and give you one more detail.

Done. At the very least, is it possible to create an alternative between \bibopenparen and \bibcloseparen (they exist) and something like \bibopenfootnote and \bibclosefootnote (indeed, they don't exist), in order to apply my toggle?

Not really. The commands are implemented so that the parentheses or footnotes are called before biblatex knows the entry type of the cited work.

I think it means that the only or easier possibile alternative is to create a dedicated citation command, precisely for this @entrytype. Indeed, in this way, I am able to easily make the command format able to switch according to the \iftoggle{}. Thank you for your attention, nonetheless!
